# É possível modificar o HTML na hora de escrever um email no Gmail?

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-chrome-extensão, gmail

A intenção é bem simples, quero fazer um `<strike>` (tachado) no texto do email, p.ex.: <strike>tachado</strike>.

Encontrei a biblioteca [KartikTalwar/gmail.js: Gmail JavaScript API](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js), mas exige umas voltas tremendas e a criação de um extensão Chrome para fazer alguma coisa parecida.

Às vezes uso [snippets JS no Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow) para manipular o DOM das páginas, mas dúvido que seja o caminho:

[image: imagem do snippets no Dev Tools]

Alguma alternativa?

Comment: Testando os limites do on-topic? :P

Comment: @bfav, ferpectamente, praticamente um [webapps.se], minha esperança eram esses links da pergunta, que são programador na veia.

Answer (score 5):

Pode-se usar diretamente a manipulação do DOM do Developer Tools que o navegador (browser) oferece. Não é direto nem bonito como criar um botão extra para formatação, mas para um programador HTML é **muito simples**:

Clique com o botão direito do mouse justo encima do texto que quer modificar e peça  <kbd>Inspecionar Elemento</kbd><sub><sup>(Inspect Element)</sup></sub>. Agora, localize o bloco de código correto no Dev Tools e de novo com o botão direito peça <kbd>Editar como HTML</kbd><sub><sup>(Edit as HTML)</sup></sub>:

[image: edit as html]

Uma vez dentro da edição HTML, modifique o código para `<strike>SEU TEXTO</strike>` e...
tá lá, Osvaldo!

[image: webmail com strike]

<sup>PS: também serve para outras tags HTML, como `<hr>`</sup>